# sqlite merge two or more rows into one from the same table

Tags: sqlite

Greeting. My problem is: I have some values in the table like

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner="Mark" AND object="apple";
+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|  id   | owner | object|amount |  
+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|  12   | Mark  | apple |   16  |  
+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|  16   | Mark  | apple |    3  |  
+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|  34   | Mark  | apple |    8  |  
+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|  34   | Mark  | apple |    0  |  
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

and the task is to grab the first one, sum to it all others amounts and then remove the rest so in the end all will be like

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|  id   | owner | object|amount |  
+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
|  12   | Mark  | apple |   27  |  
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: That would be a job for a `GROUP BY` on `owner` and `object`, and a `SUM` – but with that you will not get the `id`, since it is not allowed to select values that are not part of the grouping in SQL. So do you really need the `id` as well (and if so, what for)?

Comment: I don't really need 'id'. I've done it because guides says so. grouping them is also a good idea. then I can delete all the entries that match 'owner' and 'object' and make new one with correct data. Thanks for the input